# Deleting a row and updating UI from a UITableView for NSArray in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to delete a tableview cell. The delete action deletes the data from the server and gives successful pop up. But the cell from the table view doesn't get deleted. How can we remove data from `NSArray`? `[.remove(at: indexpath.row)]` doesn't work for NSArray. Anyone who can help me to sort out this?

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class BankDashController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var dictData:NSArray = NSArray()
    var dictData2 = [String]()
    var appDictionary:NSDictionary!
    var strId: NSArray?
    var appDictionary1: NSNumber?
    var TokenSet  = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "tokenSetAll")

    @IBOutlet weak var bankTable: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.getTaskData()

        bankTable.delegate = self
        bankTable.dataSource = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.getTaskData()
    }

    @IBAction func addBankDetails(_ sender: Any) {
        let navigati:BankDetailsController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "BankDetailsController") as! BankDetailsController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(navigati, animated: true)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dictData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:BankDashCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellDetail" as String) as! BankDashCell!

        self.appDictionary = self.dictData.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
        cell.bankName?.text =  self.appDictionary.value(forKey: "bank_name") as? String
        cell.bankDate?.text =  self.appDictionary.value(forKey: "last_visit_date") as? String
        cell.accountHolderName?.text =  self.appDictionary.value(forKey: "account_holder_name") as? String
        cell.accountNumber?.text =  self.appDictionary.value(forKey: "account_number") as? String
        cell.contactNumber?.text =  self.appDictionary.value(forKey: "contact") as? String
        cell.bankView?.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            print("self.dictData2",self.dictData)

            self.strId = (self.dictData.value(forKey: "id") as AnyObject) as? NSArray
            print("ids",self.strId! as Any)

            self.appDictionary1 = self.strId!.object(at: indexPath.row) as? NSNumber

            print("ids delete",self.appDictionary1!)

            let strinDuration:NSString = NSString(format:"http://54.89.111.171/api/user-bank-delete/%@?token=%@",self.appDictionary1!,self.TokenSet as! CVarArg) as String as String as NSString

            print("strinDuration2",strinDuration)
            let collectionviewone: String = strinDuration as String

            Alamofire.request(collectionviewone, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
                .responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response.result)
                    if let JSON = response.result.value{

                        let statu = (JSON as AnyObject).value(forKey: "status") as! NSNumber

                        if statu .isEqual(to: 1)

                        {
                            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Completed Sucessfully!!!", message: "Thank You.", preferredStyle: .alert)
                            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                        }

                        self.bankTable?.reloadData()
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    func getTaskData(){
        self.bankTable.isHidden = true
        let strinDuration:NSString = NSString(format:"http://54.89.111.171/api/user-bank-detail?token=%@",TokenSet as! CVarArg) as NSString
        let collectionviewone: String = strinDuration as String

        Alamofire.request(collectionviewone, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
            .responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response.result)
                if let JSON = response.result.value{

                    self.dictData = (JSON as AnyObject)["data"] as! NSArray
                    print("self.dictData",self.dictData)

                    if self.dictData.count > 0{

                        self.bankTable.isHidden = false
                        self.bankTable?.reloadData()

                    }else{
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` in Swift? Why do you have a variable named `appDictionary1` with a type of `NSNumber`? That's confusing. Use Swift collections and then you can more easily update the data.

Comment: rmaddy@ okie, can you please edit and update my solution ? I would be grateful to learn it.

Answer (score 0):

make dictData array mutable `var dictData:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()`

then try `dictData.removeObject(at: indexPath.row)`

Comment: Better yet, use a Swift array.

Comment: Neel Bhasin@ I got error as : Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x101907528) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x101908798).
2018-02-09 11:04:26.122383+0545 Rill Expense Manager[3216:80681] Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x101907528) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x101908798).

Answer (score 0):

Your UITableView DataSource is `NSArray` it should be `NSMutableArray` as you want to remove objects from array.

Change your dictData type `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray` like below:

```
var dictData:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
```

in `editingStyle` on success alert write below code:

```
dictData.removeObject(at: indexPath.row)
self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

Hope this will help you.

**PS** as rmaddy said you should use Swift Array and Dictionary in swift.

Comment: ivarun@ i got error as :  Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x101907528) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x101908798).
2018-02-09 11:04:26.122383+0545 Rill Expense Manager[3216:80681] Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x101907528) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x101908798).

Comment: you need to cast `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSArray`.

Comment: ivarun@ can you please explain in detail ?? I couldn;t get you.  I have given codes all there.

Comment: As you have changed dictData type `NSArray` to `NSMutableArray` you also need to change in this two lines also: `self.dictData = (JSON as AnyObject)["data"] as! NSArray` and `self.strId = (self.dictData.value(forKey: "id") as AnyObject) as? NSArray`

Comment: ivarun@It showes error as: SIGABRT on line : self.dictData = (JSON as AnyObject)["data"] as! NSMutableArray. Same error as above: Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x10d61f528) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x10d620798). 2018-02-09 11:38:53.893129+0545 Rill Expense Manager[4008:102262] Could not cast value of type '__NSSingleObjectArrayI' (0x10d61f528) to 'NSMutableArray' (0x10d620798)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `let dictData: NSArray`, use swift array as `var dictData = [NSDictionary]()` or `var dictData = [[String:Any]]()`

And when you want to remove or delete a cell form the tableview go with the below approach.

I'm assuming you are having `UITableView` object as global and `IndexPath` object which you want to delete it from tableview

i.e,

```
let _tableView = UITableView()
let _indexPath = IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0)
```

Then perform deletion action as below

```
_tableView.beginUpdates()
dictData.remove(at: _indexPath.row)
_tableView.deleteRows(at: [_indexPath], with: .fade)
_tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: Jayachandra A@ It shows error on 3 places: one at: self.dictData = ((JSON as AnyObject)["data"]  as! NSArray     error as: Cannot assign value of type '(NSArray, ())' to type '[NSDictionary]'

Comment: Jayachandra A @ second error on line: self.strId = (self.dictData.value(forKey: "id") as AnyObject) as? NSArray              error as: Value of type '[NSDictionary]' has no member 'value'

Comment: third error on line : self.appDictionary = self.dictData.object(at: indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary        error as: Value of type '[NSDictionary]' has no member 'object'

Comment: could you please share sample json response?